# Reset a List when finished

Tags: flutter

I have a list of strings that are rendered in swipeable cards. What I want to achieve is that when the users finishes the cards, There is a button to "retry again" and the list of Strings is reset and retrieved again.
This is what i achieved so far:

```
class _ExampleHomePageState extends State<ExampleHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<String> truths = [
    "Hello",
    "Hello2",
    "Hello3",
    "Hello4",
    "Hello5",
    "Hello6",
    "Hello7",
    "Hello7",
    "Hello7",
    "Hello7",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CardController controller;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          'The truth game',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
          child: TinderSwapCard(
            orientation: AmassOrientation.BOTTOM,
            totalNum: 6,
            stackNum: 4,
            swipeEdge: 4.0,
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            cardBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                '${truths[index]}',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
              )),
            ),
            cardController: controller = CardController(),
            swipeUpdateCallback: (DragUpdateDetails details, Alignment align) {
              if (align.x < 0) {
              } else if (align.x > 0) {
                return {

                };
              }
            },
            swipeCompleteCallback: (CardSwipeOrientation orientaion, int index) {
              GestureDetector(
                child: Text('try me again'),
                onTap: (){

                },
              );
            },
          )),
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        color: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        height: 70.0,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.home,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.chat_bubble,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
          Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.heart,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried setting the SetState(){} method, but its not reseting the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reset your whole widget by :

```
  void _reset() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and call it when you press your `resetbutton`

Answer (score -1):

```
    swipeCompleteCallback: (CardSwipeOrientation orientaion, int index) {
          GestureDetector(
            child: Text('try me again'),
            onTap: (){
               // add this code inside try me again..,
               truths.clear();
               setState((){});
            },
          );
        },
```

Comment: Its not doing anything

Comment: can you put it inside a button where you are resetting the list?